# Annotation is flushing in MapKit

Tags: swift, dictionary, annotations, geolocation, mapkit

I am working on MapKit in Swift and having some problem with it. I am showing annotations with image on MapKit and it is showing one image for a 100ms and showing real image after that.

```
extension MapVC: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        var annView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "pin")
        if annView == nil {
            annView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
            annView?.canShowCallout = true
        }

        let manager = SDWebImageManager.shared
        let imagePath = (annotation as! PointAnnotation).user?.photo
        manager.loadImage(with: URL(string: imagePath!), options: .continueInBackground, progress: nil) { (image, data, error, cacheType, finished, url) in
            if image != nil {
                annView?.image = image?.resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))?.circleMasked
            }
        }
        return annView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        let annotation = view.annotation
        let user = (annotation as! PointAnnotation).user
        let me = mainStore.state.profile
        if user === me {
            return
        }
        let vc = ChatVC.storyBoardInstance
        vc.user = user
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

please help me on this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code before `loadImage`.

```
annView?.image = nil

manager.loadImage(with:....
```

**EDITED**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var annView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "pin")
    if annView == nil {
        annView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
        annView?.canShowCallout = true

        let manager = SDWebImageManager.shared
        let imagePath = (annotation as! PointAnnotation).user?.photo
        manager.loadImage(with: URL(string: imagePath!), options: .continueInBackground, progress: nil) { (image, data, error, cacheType, finished, url) in
            if image != nil {
                annView?.image = image?.resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize(width: 16, height: 16))?.circleMasked
            }
        }
    } else {
        annView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    return annView
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's still not working. I did `self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)` in viewDidAppear and add annotations again. Is this reason of this issue?

Comment: Thank you @Kosuke Ogawa I tried your code, and It's changing the avatar everytime I open map.